I want to display the skill sets like in a progress bar in Android studio using java
I just didn't get any reference video or like any other blog and I didn't know how to implement
I want to display the skill sets in the progress bar that shows the level of my skill with indicated number and it gradually increase when it came to viewpoint
enter image description here
I want to display like this any sort of ways to do that and alternatives will be much help
